# Trigonometric Curve Fitting with Phase Shift

Tags: trigonometry, polynomials, approximation, regression, trigonometric-series

I have a similar situation as described her

[Initial Guess for Trigonometric Curve Fitting](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4556327/initial-guess-for-trigonometric-curve-fitting/4556609#4556609)

However, now I would like to fit measured data as described in the linked post with a polynoimal of the form

$$y=A_0+\sum_{n=1}^pA_n\cos(n\varphi - \alpha_n)$$
with a possible phase-shift $\alpha_n$ (it could be the case, that $\alpha_n = n \cdot \alpha$ for a constant $\alpha$; this would make sense in the physical context but is not however proofed in any way).

Is a approach as described in the link post here possible as well?

Comment: $\cos(n\varphi-\alpha_n) = \cos(n\varphi) \cos(\alpha_n) + \sin(n\varphi) \sin(\alpha_n)$, then consider a model like$$\hat y = A_0 + \sum_n \left(B_n \cos(n\varphi) + C_n \sin(n\varphi)\right)$$with $B_n=A_n\cos(\alpha_n)$ and $C_n=A_n\sin(\alpha_n)$

Comment: Can I than by coefficient comparing extract the phase shift $\alpha_n$ and Amplitude $B_n$?

Comment: Ah, of course I can just use $\tan$ to get the value of alpha

Comment: As you can see, it is the same problem as earlier